# C# UWP - how to pass additional parameter to an event handler at runtime

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, uwp

I am uploading huge files on S3 by parts / chunks. I need to pass additional parameter to event handler.

I have some code for uploading file / stream parts and I need to pass filesize to this event handler.

```
uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress += new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>(UploadPartProgressEventCallback);
```

And I need to add there parameter with filesize:

```
uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress += new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>(UploadPartProgressEventCallback(**filesize**));
```

My eventhandler:

```
public async void UploadPartProgressEventCallback(object sender, StreamTransferProgressArgs e)
    {}
```

I need this:

```
public async void UploadPartProgressEventCallback(object sender, StreamTransferProgressArgs e, long contentLength)
    {}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress += new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>((s, e) => UploadPartProgressEventCallback(s, e, contentLength));
```

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.